# Several questions with silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm new to Silverlight, haven't done any project yet. My company is going to start a project which should be 100% silverlight and ria services. Though I've read a book on sl, without some practical experience, I still have some questions left. Hope I can find help here :)

Here are my questions.

- The project we are going to build needs both authentication and authorization. I can use Asp.Net membership provider, but there's a problem. During authentication process (Login), the user should provide username, password and temporary pin code. As far as I know, Membership provider doesn't support authentication with more than 2 params(username and password). Is there any workaround on this problem? Maybe I can create my own MembershipProvider? Will this solve the problem?
- We plan to use WCF Duplex services and RIA services in a single silverlight application. We want to use duplex services to let a user know when a transaction status changes. What's your experience with this? Is duplex services reliable or we should go the old way, checking the transaction status in interval?
- The application should run inside the browser and outside too. My question is if it's possible to run sl app as OOB when we want to use authentication/authorization + RIA Services + Duplex Services? Should we wait somekind of problem here?

I think that's it for now.
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Membership Question: No, no workarounds... you will have to write your won membership provider... ive done that... its not that hard... but be caerfull or u might fall in a big maintance problem... as i did...

Comment: Yep, I found that I can extend IAuthentication<T>. It's Login method has a customData as last parameter and I can use that parameter to pass the temporary pin code. This problem is solved, other's remain :)
Thanks :)